# Is there an alternative for the random module in Python?

Tags: python

I was using [Trypython.org](http://www.trypython.org), and found that there was no random module included, so got curious.

Is there an alternative method to generate random numbers within a certain range without importing random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite ugly, unreliable, and not really fast, but it works :

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.time()
>>> int(str(t-int(t))[2:])%100 #Keeping only the numbers after the decimal point, otherwise you would get the same "random" number each second
33
```

The range here is [0,99] (cf the modulo 100).
Use it at your own risk.

Comment: That's no (pseudo)random number, or if it is strictly according to some definition, it's an extremely poor one. You'd probably be better off generating some by hand, there are methods for that. -1

Comment: I didn't say it was great either. It's just a trick if the OP doesn't want to spend some time on the subject.

Comment: +1 for the lateral thinking. You could have saved a lot of time by just doing int(100*(t-int(t))

Comment: I dare say it's not even a viable trick. Selling this as any kind of randomness whatsoever is false. And as for spending time: Well I'm sorry but randomness is far too tricky to be done without some thought/research. (If you just want a couple of numbers that aren't terribly predictable just from looking at the code which generates them, it *may* be fine, but that's not randomness, please don't call it that.) Aside from manual methods (which I admit are impractical if you need many numbers), there are almost-as-simple (imperfect, but better than this) PRNG algorithms. Check wikipedia.

Comment: @delnan: I'm a programming newbie, so please tell me what the problem with the above approach is... you mean it is not random because if we write the above code as a function and call it in computed intervals we'll get same numbers? is that it? or is there an even more sinister reason?

Comment: @mankand007 That's one problem, but there's more: (1) You can't reproduce a sequence of outputs by passing the same seed again. Seems non-random (it is, it can only work for *Pseudo*-RNGs), but is very useful for some use cases, e.g. debugging. (2) Depending on clock precision and CPU speed, it may generate the same number far more frequently, or never. While real random numbers may be distributed in any way, `def random(): return 0` is not a (useful) RNG. (3) With `time.time()` specifically, it may *always* yield 0, because the precision of `time.time` may be >1 second (http://bit.ly/KeuMkc).

Answer (score 2):

Generating random, or rather pseudo-random numbers is tricky business and it's best to stick to the default libraries. I would recommend you bite the bullet and download Python [2.7.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/) or [3.2.3](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2.3/) and then you can play around with any other libraries not included by trypython as well.

Comment: Well, this is my workplace, and I don't want to install software on this machine. The bullet and the intent to bite are there, but i'm pretty much toothless here.. :)

Comment: @mankind007 Why not use portable python off a flash drive or some type of portable hard drive?

Comment: @jamylak: The security policies are pretty strict here so, that's strictly a no-no..

Answer (score 2):

Randomness is not a trivial subject, so instead of an alternative module, I suggest an alternative online IDE instead.

Take a look at [pythonfiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/). Here is the code you should use there:

```
import random
print random.randint(1, 100)
```

Comment: I know there are alternatives, but asked the question just out of curiosity to see if there are any clever/dirty methods available in python...

Comment: @mankand007: Apologies, looking at your other replies I assumed you were trying to make something specific using online tools due to limitations imposed by your work environment

Comment: Well, that was part of the initial intention, but I aimed to gain more than just an alternate URL.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Random number generation does not have to be hard. What's hard is inventing your own method and finding a proof that it's good, or writing an optimized/secure/thread safe/.../ implementation.

Here's my Python version of the Multiply-with-carry method as described at 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods

You will get quite good and uniform random numbers between 0 and 1 by calling getuniform(), then just scale them to the size you need. This should be fine for most cases except cryptography or detailed Monte Carlo simulations.

```
class myrandom:
    kz=36969
    kw=18000
    k3=65535
    maxz=kz*k3+(2<<16)
    maxw=kw*k3+(2<<16)
    max=(maxz<<16 )+maxw
    # Optionally initiate with different seed. Two numbers below 2<<16
    def __init__(self,z=123456789,w=98764321):
        self.m_w = w
        self.m_z = z
    def step(self):
        self.m_z = self.kz * (self.m_z & self.k3) + (self.m_z >> 16)  
        self.m_w = self.kw * (self.m_w & self.k3) + (self.m_w >> 16)       
    def get(self):
        self.step()
        return (self.m_z << 16) + self.m_w
    def time_reseed(self):
        # yes, sure, move out import if you like to
        import time
        t=int(time.time())
        # completely made up way to got two new numbers below 2<<16
        self.m_z = (self.m_z+(t*34567891011)) & ((2<<16)-1)
        self.m_w = (self.m_w+(t*10987654321)) & ((2<<16)-1)
        self.step()
    def getuniform(self):
        return self.get()*1.0/self.max
```

Example:

```
myr=myrandom()
print [myr.getuniform() for x in range(20)]
```

if you call time_reseed() some bits of new randomness from time() is added to the state.

Comment: I'm not able to see any indents. Please update the code. Thanks!

Comment: @mankand007, I'm not sure why you can't read the indents. Should be fine. Try reloading again please.

Answer (score 0):

Use "secrets" module- It is a built in module:
import secrets
secrets.random(10)
IT GENERATES A NUMBER BETWEEN 0 TO 10 OR VALUE BY YOU!