# How to Generate Random Numbers with using while loop and without using random methods?

Tags: python

```
while True :
    number = int(1, 6)
    if number != 0 :
        print(number)
        break
    else :
        number = int( 1, 6)
        print(number+1)
        break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative for random module in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930386/alternative-for-random-module-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the line:

```
number = int(1, 6)
```

is where you want to generate a random integer to assign to the variable number, with your question being whether or not there exists a function not utilizing the random package that could replace int()

```
import datetime
import math
def randoWOrando(range1,range2):
    randTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    randString = '0.' + randTime.strftime('%f')[:2]
    output = range1 + int(round(float(randString)*(range2-range1), 0))
    return output
```

This function uses the current time in microsecond as a decimal number and cuts off the first two digits to be turned into a float number between one and zero. This is then multiplied to the given range, rounded, and then cast into an integer. With the minimum added, it yields a random number between the two numbers.